# Is this a safe and efficient way to handle the reading of null values in a DB using Generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have been playing with generics and was hoping I could get some feedback or suggestions on a function I created to help handle reading null values from the DB.  My main concern is in the if statement.  Is there a better way to find out if T is a string ect.?  Thanks.

```
public static T CheckNull<T>(object value)
    {
        if ((value != null) && value.Equals(DBNull.Value))
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(typeof(T), typeof(String)))
                value = string.Empty;
            else if (object.ReferenceEquals(typeof(T), typeof(Boolean)))
                value = false;
            else
                value = null;
        }
        return (T)value;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you all.  Now I only check if it is a string and return string.Empty else default(T) to cover other types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of `T`'s type, you can fall back to `default(T)` which will provide the default value for the given type (<strike>`string.Empty`</strike>, `0`, `false`, `null`, etc...) :

```
value = default(T);
```

Edit: `default(string)` does, however, return `null`.

Comment: Calling `default(string)` returns `null`, not an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You need also to cover other primitive data types.

```
value = default(T);
```

This return null if it is a reference type, otherwise 0, false or whatever is an appropriate default value of the given type T.

**Note:** default(string) is `null`, not string.Empty. If you want it to be `String.Empty`, you need to implement this as an exception.